# why all thing is stop when i'll use while loop in MouseEntered() Function ?? In Java

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, mouseevent, jlabel

My **gui** programme that contains **(JPanel ,JFrame ,JLabel)** JLabel : I Coded it To move from
**(0x, 0y)** To **(200x ,0y)** Pixel by Pixel . it will start when i put the mouse on the panel called **"p"** ,but when i try to run this programme it's start correctly ,but when i put my mouse on the panel all thing stop to a few seconds The Label Moved to Point **(200x, 0y)** Any One Had Any Answer To Solve This Problem.

The Class Had The Problem :-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class JFrameClass extends JFrame{
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    
    public JFrameClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setSize(800, 800);
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        l.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        l.setBackground(new Color(16, 16, 16));
        l.setOpaque(true);
        
        p.setBounds(320, 320, 100, 100);
        p.setBackground(new Color(16, 16, 16));
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                boolean wd = true;
                int x = 0;
                while(true) {
                    if(x == 200) wd = false;
                    if(!wd) break;
                    l.setLocation(x, 0);
                    x++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
        
        
        add(p);
        add(l);
        
        
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The Main Class That Run The JFrameClass class :-

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrameClass();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: while ( true ) -> endless loop. You'll never reach the break; since you never re-assign x

Comment: @Stultuske No, he has a break case, it's just a little clunky.  His real issue is doing application work on the EVT.

Comment: @Ryan indeed, he has a break, and I've explained why that will never be reached.

Comment: It is reached.  But that's not his problem. If you execute the code, it takes 2 seconds to complete.  His issue is a UI-update on the main thread.  Basically, the component is getting moved but the notification isn't being sent to the UI manager until it's complete.

Comment: yeah, I missed the x++; line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your code on the Event-Dispatch-Thread.  That's a no-no. Put the code in your mouseEntered into a SwingWorker.

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                 protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                     for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
                         l.setVisible(false);
                         l.setLocation(x, 0);
                         l.setVisible(true);
                         try {
                             Thread.sleep(10);
                         }catch(Exception e) {
                             
                         }
                     }
                     return null;
                 }
             };
             worker.execute();
```

Comment: Doesn't work ,but thanks

Comment: Ah I see your problem now.  I thought you were dealing with a threading pause, but it's a UI update issue. Updated the code in the answer to reflect that.

Comment: You should NOT update the location of the Swing component in the background Thread. All updates to Swing components should be done on the EDT. If you want animation use a Swing Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Listener methods like `mouseEntered()` are expected to return quickly, within at most a few milliseconds, as Java will start processing the next user interface event only when the previous event processing has finished.

Your `mouseEntered()` will loop 200 times, with every iteration sleeping for 10msec. So, Java will pause its complete UI event handling until these 2 seconds have passed, meaning to completely freeze the UI for this time.

If you want to create a moving label, you need to use a `Timer` or something similar.